# how to use file pointers to edit a text document after a specific line or word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have to check if a certain word is there in a file , say "exe" and then find if in that sentence itself if there is a word , say "mba", then I have to delete "exe" and after the word thousand i should add "executive".
The rs and thousand don't appear next to next. I have now split the file into lines and checked. But I don't know how to omit "exe" from file and how to put "executive" after "mba". Can u help me on how to use the seekg and seekp or can u give any other solution to this.

```
f = open(fi+'.o2','r')
ff = open(fi+'.o3','w')
lin = 1
word_count = 1
word = "exe"
word1 = "mba"
for line in f:
    if word in line:
       print "found in" ,lin
       if word1 in line:
          print "yes at",word_count
word_count = word_count + 1
lin = lin + 1
```

sample input file:

- this exe is a mba person
- this exe combo offer is for mba only.
- the exe suite is for mba person.

the output file should be like:

- this is a mba executive person
- this combo offer is for mba executive only.
- the suite is for mba executive person.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your file looks like, what you want to get/change, etc.

Comment: @sshashank124 I have edited the que with a sample input and output

Comment: can i just replace the word mba with "mba executive".. can i read a file and just replace certain words alone??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
import re

f = open(fi+'.o2','r')
# f = ['this exe is a mba person',
#      'this exe combo offer is for mba only.',
#      'the exe suite is for mba person.']
word = 'exe'
word1 = 'mba'

for line in f:
    # check if both words are in the line
    if word in line and word1 in line:
        # remove the 'exe' and a space
        subs = re.sub(r'\bexe ', '', line)
        # replace 'mba' with 'mba executive'
        print(re.sub(r'\bmba\b', r'mba executive', subs))

# this is a mba executive person
# this combo offer is for mba executive only.
# the suite is for mba executive person.
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/EgHDW8)